# AngularJS not working in modal popup

Tags: angularjs

I have my code but it seems like the angularjs codes are not working. I dont know whats the problem though I already did these things:

```
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
```

these too

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also these

```
    var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

and

```
     <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </modal>
```

and finally these:

```
     <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-12 text_right" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                    <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">SAVE</button>



</div>
<script>

var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    };
  });

mymodal.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
     <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </modal>

</script>
```

and i don't know what seems to be the problem please help

Comment: Could you please put this on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: i think your ng-app shoould be equal to "mymodal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', []);

to

var mymodal = angular.module('exampleApp', []);